# How do I cast to generic type?

Tags: java, generics, casting

The following code produces an "unchecked or unsafe operation" warning, how can I cast the `Object` `o` to type `T` without causing the warning?  I know that I could suppress the warning, but I want to know the "correct" way.

```
public class MyType<T> {
    T cast(Object o) {
        return (T)o; //<--- what causes the warning
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're doing isn't type safe, so yes, you're going to get a warning that it's not type safe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). You can pass the `Class<T>` as an argument, and use that. Like,

```
T cast(Class<T> cls, Object o) {
    return cls.cast(o);
}
```

**or** even

```
public class MyType {
    public static <T> T cast(Class<T> cls, Object o) {
        return cls.cast(o);
    }
}
```

which you can call like

```
int t = MyType.cast(Integer.class, 10);
```

*Alternatively*, but on the same lines, you could pass the `Class` in the constructor like

```
public class MyType<T> {
    public MyType(Class<T> cls) {
        this.cls = cls;
    }

    private Class<T> cls;

    T cast(Object o) {
        return cls.cast(o);
    }
}
```

And then use it like

```
MyType<Integer> myType = new MyType<>(Integer.class);
int t = myType.cast(10);
```

Comment: Hi Elllioitt how do you pass Class<T> as an argument? Can you show me a concrete example?

Comment: `String foo = cast(String.class, "foo");`

Comment: @Tania What do you need that cast method for at all? In which context is MyType going to be used?

Comment: public class GenericCastTest {
    
    public class MyType<T> {
        public void add(Integer i) {
            T t = (T)i; //<--- work with warning
            
            T a = cast(Integer.class, i); //<--- compiler error
        }
        
        T cast(Class<T> cls, Object o) {
            return cls.cast(o);
        }
    }
}

Comment: `Integer a = cast(Integer.class, i);`

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying my question. Let's see if I can do better.

Comment: I want to do T t = (T) o; where o is any object. This line will compile but with the warning. What I want to do is to cast o to Type T(not integer, not string, but exactly the generic type T) without generating any warning.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want the compiler to warn you about something that could ultimately throw a ClassCastException?

Comment: I just wonder if there is some kind of method like Elliott suggested that will solve the problem. Like a reverse generic type cast!?

Comment: I think you have three choices - (1) pass in the class as Elliott suggested, (2) use `@SuppressWarnings` (3) just live with the warning.  Ultimately, the warning is a good one.

Comment: Suppressed warnings should always include a comment why it's safe anyway. Meanwhile the `Class<T>` approach is standard, usually implemented as a final instance member passed via the constructor. The `Class<T>` instance is called a "runtime type token" (RTTT), and gives you generics at runtime. Unlike languages like C#, Java doesn't give you runtime generics by default, but contrary to hysterical reports, it does give you a way to achieve them. You just have to pass the RTTT explicitly to the code that needs it.

Comment: Hi Everyone thanks for your answers.